# "start chrome" working in command line without PATH variable

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, command-line-tool

I tried executing "start chrome" in the command line and it opened chrome. I checked the PATH variables and nothing related to chrome there, how could it have worked? Is it different on your side? I'm running Windows 10.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Windows CMD apparently no longer relies entirely on PATH; I see exactly the same behavior, and `where chrome` doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Windows (to include cmd.exe and explorer.exe) will now search `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\<exe_name>\` after checking the path (and failing).

I just verified this behavior using the System Internals Process Monitor.

Chances are, this behavior is part of the Win32 API call `ShellExecuteEx()`.